# How do the "Baby White Walkers" become old (bearded) White Walkers?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In season 4 we see that Craster's last son is taken by a White Walker and eventually laid on a sort of ice altar, the Night King then touches the baby with his finger and shortly after the eyes turn blue, the same colour as the White Walker's eyes.

So eh, what then, does it suddenly grow a beard, lose its teeth and grow to being 6 foot tall? Is there any explanation to what happens next?

Comment: Nope. No legit explanation anywhere afaik :).  So, my theory is, it remains a baby wight walker with a little baby ice sword.

Comment: @Dawny33 Aka "white crawlers".

Comment: Relevant on SFF: [How does a baby who is turned into white walker grow into an adult White Walker?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/133486/54887)

Comment: We don't know, yet. All answers will be speculation.

Comment: @Aegon thanks! I couldn't find that. What do I do now, delete this (seeing as it's basically a duplicate)?

Comment: @Aegon, the knight king is not bearded so he does shave :)

Comment: @SilverBebs He didn't have a beard when he was turned: it's not been confirmed or denied that the original White Walker ages (and therefore doesn't have to deal with things like beard growth). A lot about the Night King is a mystery, so making an assumption like "He can grow beards" is risky.

Comment: @ThomasYates No you don't have to delete it. And it's not a dupe (As the same question doesn't exist on this SE AFAIK). If you want to build an answer yourself based on that, feel free to do so.

Comment: @SilverBebs Or perhaps he just can't grow a proper beard ;) I should know.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The short answer is that we do not know what happens to the baby white walkers.

The longer answer is that we do not know what happens to the baby white walkers, but we can speculate. I'll start off by quoting what we know:

- The Night King was created thousands of years ago during the war between the First Men and the Children of the Forest.
- The Children of the Forest created the first White Walker - The Night King.
- The Night King can create White Walkers from alive baby boys.
- There are now old looking bearded White Walkers.

As such we can deduce that the ageing process of the white walkers is a lot different to men as the Night King is still alive and doesn't appear to have grown older.

If we take all of this into account it would **appear** that only the Night King has created White Walkers and only from baby boys. This would mean that White Walkers do age but differently to men and as such we don't know for sure.

---

Alternatively, there could be an army of white crawlers out there and the bearded ones are just older men that have been turned by the Night King.

> [image]
>   <sup>Found on [Google here](https://www.google.co.uk/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fs-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com%2Foriginals%2F1e%2F03%2F6b%2F1e036b0c72aa87de419cba8a43b5d1e5.jpg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.pinterest.com%2Fpin%2F336644140873582082%2F&docid=d_WsAoQhvf7jKM&tbnid=2qfpuljB_sGUHM%3A&vet=10ahUKEwj6gKHWzu_VAhUpAcAKHYqrBA8QMwgpKAQwBA..i&w=886&h=1369&bih=928&biw=1280&q=game%20of%20thrones%20white%20crawlers%20meme&ved=0ahUKEwj6gKHWzu_VAhUpAcAKHYqrBA8QMwgpKAQwBA&iact=mrc&uact=8), clicks through to Pinterest. According to @Chris the original is from [here on deviant art](https://azad-injejikian.deviantart.com/art/White-Crawler-ASoIaF-Game-of-Thrones-451077090).</sup>

Comment: There hasn't been any instance of an adult human being converted into a White Walker IIRC. Maybe older ones can't be converted at all? Otherwise why have Wights when you can have infinitely more dangerous Kinsmen of your own kind.

Comment: @Aegon I don't think there has been which is why I only speculated at it (though the second part of my answer wasn't too serious). And I'm guessing because they can't capture everyone alive. Though with the new addition to the army I'm not too sure how that statement will hold up.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder The latest addition could be considered a child tho. The addition's kind lives for centuries and what is he? 2-3 years old? And we don't if they converted it into a Wight (Like the dead bear) or one of them

Comment: @Aegon It could be considered a child you're right and whether it is a wight or white walker is why I wasn't too sure with that statement.