# Where are the other White Walkers converted from babies?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In season 4 we see that Craster's last son is taken by a White Walker and it seems that the Night King convert him as a White Walker.

Since Craster has 19 wives at the time of the War of the Five Kings, he might have given more than one boys to white walkers.

Where are those boys now? There is no clue about child White Walkers in the series, and we can see few White Walkers with the Nights King.

Is there a possibility that there are more White Walkers (converted Craster's kids) with the Night King?

Comment: They be on their way for a sight-seeing trip south of the Wall.

Comment: *"There is no clue about child White Walkers in the series"* - which makes this entirely speculative and so off-topic.

Comment: This goes against the future works policy. We don't know where the babies have gone. We haven't seen in the Walkers live anywhere, or have any location. As far as we have seen, the Walkers are nomadic as we have always seen them "on the road". We can't answer this without speculating.

Comment: [Very related](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/53454/how-many-white-walkers-are-there)

Comment: [Also related](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/79413/how-do-the-baby-white-walkers-become-old-bearded-white-walkers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, asking where are other White Walkers now is specualtive.

To answer "are there more Walkers than what we saw?": **most likely**.

One possible explanation that I have in my head when watching the show is that they have work to do. For example, in last episode (S07E06) Jon's party attacks group of wight led by one Walker. When Walker is killed most wights fall down. My understanding is that many Walkers are sent throughout the (real) north to raise any bodies they can find. All the unburned dead, humans or animals, can now be raised by Walkers to join their army. That could be also one reason Night King goes slow. He is simply "harvesting" with his Walkers and army is amassing at that mountain. Jon's party simply met one Walker returning from one of those Walkers returing from one of those missions.

Other explanations might be budget or Night King actually hiding the real numbers of Walkers... but Walkers actually having other missions is more cool IMO.

Comment: *"asking where are other White Walkers now is specualtive."* which is why you shouldn't answer it.